# RuntimeError: "element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn"

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, model, training-data, kaggle

Hello PyTorch community,

I hope this message finds you well. I am facing an issue while training a comment classification model using PyTorch Lightning with a pre-trained BERT model.

I encountered the following error during the training process:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

To provide some context, I have already enabled gradients for all parameters of the model using the function enable_gradients(model). However, the error still persists.

The model I am using is based on the aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv02-twitter pre-trained model, and I noticed that some weights of the BERT model were not initialized properly upon loading. I have ensured that I am using the latest versions of PyTorch, Transformers, and PyTorch Lightning.

I attempted to pretrain the BERT model on a downstream task before training my specific model, but the error remains unresolved.

I am reaching out to the community for any guidance or insights on how to resolve this issue. I would be more than happy to provide additional details about my training environment, code, and model setup if needed.

Thank you in advance for your support and advice. Your expertise and suggestions are highly appreciated.
this is my code :

```
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer

def enable_gradients(model):
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True

# datamodule
ucc_data_module = UCC_Data_Module(train_path, val_path, test_path, attributes=attributes, batch_size=config['batch_size'])
ucc_data_module.setup()

# model
model = UCC_Comment_Classifier()

enable_gradients(model)

# trainer and fit
# Instantiation of the Lightning Trainer
trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=config['n_epochs'], accelerator='gpu', num_sanity_val_steps=1)

try:
    trainer.fit(model, ucc_data_module)
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Best regards,

This is the error :

ProcessRaisedException:

-- Process 1 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 69, in _wrap
fn(i, *args)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/launchers/multiprocessing.py", line
147, in _wrapping_function
results = function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 568, in _fit_impl
self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 973, in _run
results = self._run_stage()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1016, in _run_stage
self.fit_loop.run()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 201, in run
self.advance()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 354, in advance
self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 133, in run
self.advance(data_fetcher)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 218, in
advance
batch_output = self.automatic_optimization.run(trainer.optimizers[0], kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 185, in
run
self._optimizer_step(kwargs.get("batch_idx", 0), closure)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 260, in
_optimizer_step
call._call_lightning_module_hook(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 144, in
_call_lightning_module_hook
output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1256, in optimizer_step
optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 155, in step
step_output = self._strategy.optimizer_step(self._optimizer, closure, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/ddp.py", line 256, in optimizer_step
optimizer_output = super().optimizer_step(optimizer, closure, model, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 225, in
optimizer_step
return self.precision_plugin.optimizer_step(optimizer, model=model, closure=closure, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 114,
in optimizer_step
return optimizer.step(closure=closure, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py", line 69, in wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 280, in wrapper
out = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py", line 439, in step
loss = closure()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 101,
in _wrap_closure
closure_result = closure()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 140, in
**call**
self._result = self.closure(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 135, in
closure
self._backward_fn(step_output.closure_loss)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 232, in
backward_fn
call._call_strategy_hook(self.trainer, "backward", loss, optimizer)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 291, in
_call_strategy_hook
output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 200, in backward
self.precision_plugin.backward(closure_loss, self.lightning_module, optimizer, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py", line 67,
in backward
model.backward(tensor, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1046, in backward
loss.backward(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 487, in backward
torch.autograd.backward(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py", line 200, in backward
Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for you is to add `torch.set_grad_enabled(True)` at the beginning for `training_step`, or use the AdamW optimizer from torch.